# Android - Moveing an Activity inside of background thread

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

Every time I`m trying to finish an activity inside of a timer method, the activity comes back alive over and over again.
I running this activity:

```
public class PlayerNoAdmin extends ActionBarActivity {

    Timer myTimer; boolean isAdmin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_no_admin);

        Intent oldIntent = getIntent();
        if (oldIntent != null && oldIntent.hasExtra("THE_LIST")){
            songs = oldIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("THE_LIST");
            id = oldIntent.getIntExtra("ID",0);
            listId = oldIntent.getIntExtra("LIST_ID",0);
            isAdmin = oldIntent.getBooleanExtra("IS_ADMIN",false);
        }

        //update the list every k seconds
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TimerMethod();
            }

        }, 0, k_time2Update);
    }

    private void TimerMethod() {
        //This method is called directly by the timer
        //and runs in the same thread as the timer.

        //We call the method that will work with the UI
        //through the runOnUiThread method.
        this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);

    }

    private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Here check for update in the list every 30 seconds and send the new location
            String url = getRunUrl();
            new TaskMusicPlay().execute(url);
        }
    };

    private class TaskMusicPlay extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String jsonResult = null;
            try {
                String url = params[0];
                TestMain client = new TestMain();
                jsonResult = client.doGetRequest(url);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return  jsonResult;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            checkIfNew(aVoid);
        }

        private void checkIfNew(String result) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                String temp = object.getJSONObject("info").getString("isAdmin");
                isAdmin = (temp.equals("true"));
                    if (isAdmin) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(),YouTubePlayer.class);
                        intent.putExtra("THE_LIST", songs);
                        intent.putExtra("ID", id);
                        intent.putExtra("LIST_ID",listId);
                        intent.putExtra("IS_ADMIN",isAdmin);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the end, I succeeded to move to the YouTubePlayer activity, but every few seconds the app returns to the code of this activity (and then executes again the startActivity call and goes back to YouTubePlayer) and that's going on and on.

Comment: I would say the timer doesn't stop or the last activity in the backstay is always calling your activity to start over and over again.

Comment: @IljaKO thanks, do you know how I can stop the timer? or stop calling the activity?

Comment: i give you an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Timer is periodically calling the player to start over and over again.

You must make a cancel() call to the Timer if it is no longer needed so you prevent it from holding a reference for your activity and thus preventing from being removed from the backstack and GC.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

And your Timer is not running on the same thread as it's code because the timer thread iis another Thread and the Code in the Timer is running on UI. You can check it out by adding some logs in the Timer's run method outside of the runOnUIThread() and inside of it.